# Restar 2 horas en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, matemáticas

Tengo la siguiente query donde resto 2 horas

```
SELECT   (b.hora_termino - b.hora_inicio) as resta FROM db.produccion_dia
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado = `06:30:00`

**Pero me gustaría obtenerlo así =**
**6.5**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He leido que con `to_char` pero igual no me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Eh, pues se me ocurre que proceses el resultado como string. El ejemplo usa current_time pero pues, ahí iría el resultado de tu resta.

```
SELECT array_to_string(
  string_to_array( CAST(current_time AS varchar), ':'), '.'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Conviértelo a `TO_NUMBER` y luego utiliza la función

```
ROUND(resta,2)
```

Comment: que hace TO_NUMBER  y que hace ROUND y por que le estas pasando 2 parametros???

Answer (score 0):

¿30 minutos, cuanto representan de 1 hora? simple: `30 / 60 = 0.5` de 1 hora,  con los segundos es igual: 15 segundos representan `15 / 3600 = 0.0041` de 1 hora:

```
select T.Tiempo,
       extract(hour from T.Tiempo) + 
       (extract(minute from T.Tiempo) / 60) +
       (extract(seconds from T.Tiempo) / 3600)
       from (select CAST('13:30:00' AS TIME) - CAST('07:00:00' AS TIME) as Tiempo) T
```